# Elasticsearch - How to index the same field with different analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch

I am interested in indexing the same text field with different analyzers, both stemmed to allow inexact matching and with shingles for proximity matching. 
From this blogpost https://www.elastic.co/blog/multi-field-search-just-got-better I understand that this is possible, but I am not sure what is the correct way to do it. 
Should I just index the field twice as different fields, each with another analyzer, or is there a way to specify two analyzers for the same field?

Answer (score 4):

```
  message: {
    properties: {
      text: {
        type: 'string',
        index: 'analyzed',
        analyzer: 'custom_text_analyzer',
        fields: {
          standard: {
            type: 'string',
            index: 'analyzed',
            analyzer: 'standard'
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

Here's one way to do it, you can just add extra fields onto a property and give it whatever properties you want when you index on your server. In this case, when I want to reference this field I just do my query on *text.standard* instead of *text*.

Comment: Thanks! with the help of your answer I also managed to find where this is discussed in the documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: Glad to be of help, be sure to check an answer if you accept it! We're all rep whores here.